# Symfony 2.6 - Translation does not work

Tags: php, symfony

I've installed fresh symfony2, and I tried to translate text, but in debug:translation, ids are duplicated, and twig output shows me Id, not Message Preview text. What is wrong?

app/console debug:translation output:

```
+----------+-----------+----------------------+
| State(s) | Id        | Message Preview (en) |
+----------+-----------+----------------------+
| x        | base.test | base.test            |
| o        | base.test | This is test         |
+----------+-----------+----------------------+
```

twig input:

```
{% trans %}base.test{% endtrans %}
```

twig output:

```
base.test
```

base.en.yml:

```
base.test: This is test
```

Comment: try `{{ 'base.test' | trans }}`

Comment: Can you show us the full base.en.yml ?

Comment: This is full base.en.yml - only one line

Comment: {% trans with 'base' %}base.test{% endtrans %} does not help. {% trans_default_domain "app" %} does not help. {{ 'base.test' | trans }} does not help. - when i change default domain, the debug:translate shows that everything is ok, with no id duplication, but still - twig output shows only Id. cache:clear also does not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the translation domain.

```
{% trans from "base" %}base.test{% endtrans %}
```

And configure your config.yml :

```
framework
    translator: { fallback: en }
```

Comment: Now - debug:translation shows that everything is ok, but in twig template I still see only message id instead of message text.

Comment: Do you have it in your config.yml ?

`framework:
    translator: { fallback: en }`